# How do I line-wrap justifications in a proof?

Tags: align, amsmath, alignment, proof-package, justification

How would I line-wrap justifications in the proof/align environment in LaTeX?
E.g., I have a justification for an equation, but the justification veers off into the page and doesn't line wrap. I'd like the justification to be split off and continue onto the next line, and of course, the next equation-justification pair should be shifted down accordingly. As a bonus, I'd also like the equation to have a set indentation from the margin (i.e., be displaced from the alignment of the problem number).

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\title{Example}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\justif}[2]{&{#1}&\text{#2}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{proof}

\begin{align*}
dog_{k+1} &= dog_{k} \justif{\quad}{The robot ate a chicken which was undercooked; ergo, the count of phones in the world remains the same and fixed as prior.}\\
cat_{k+1} &= cat_{k} \justif{\quad}{Cat likes running more than sleeping.}\\
\end{align*}

The inductive step is complete.

\end{proof}


\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Picture of mishapen line:

[image]

Comment: i would use a `&&\parbox[t]...` and adjust the width until it looks right.

Comment: off topic: don't leave a blank line before `\end{proof}` to avoid having the tombstone on a separate line (and perhaps after a page break).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple possibility; the justification use the remaining space when the equations have been placed. It relies on the `linegoal` package, which measures the horizontal remaining  space at the current point of the line.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\title{Example}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\justif}[2]{&{#1}&\rlap{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{\footnotesize#2}}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{proof}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
dog_{k+1} &= dog_{k} \justif{\quad}{The robot ate a chicken which was undercooked; ergo, the count of phones in the world remains the same and fixed as prior.}\\
cat_{k+1} &= cat_{k} \justif{\quad}{Cat likes running more than sleeping.}\\
\end{alignat*}

The inductive step is complete.
\end{proof}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Another solution uses `\flalign`,and you choose the width  of of the justification via an optional argument (default: `0.3\linewidth`). The formulæ are aligned and centred in the space on the left of the justifications with this code:

```
\newcommand{\fljustif}[2][0.3\linewidth]{\parbox[t]}
...................
 \begin{flalign*}
& & dog_{k+1} &= dog_{k} & \fljustif{The robot ate a chicken which was undercooked; ergo, the count of phones in the world remains the same and fixed as prior.}\\
& & cat_{k+1} &= cat_{k} & \fljustif{Cat likes running more than sleeping.}\\
\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your second example missing a closing brace?

Comment: @Davislor: Oh! yes – a copy-paste accident. Thank you for pointing it!